# How to access React class function inside Redux dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

The toggleModal() function toggles a local state. After dispatching an async function, I want to close the modal. However there's no way for me to access the class function inside dispatch.

The issue can be solved by moving the modal state to the store, but I would like to keep this value local to the class.

I tried passing the modal value as a prop, while I can access the value using ownProps inside the dispatch function, it's a read-only value.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props) 
        this.state = { modal: false }
    }

    onClick() {

        // OPTION (1)
        // reduxFunction is not a promise, so then doesn't work
        this.props.reduxFunction().then(() => {
            this.toggleModal()
        })

        // OPTION (2)
        // This needs to fire after async function
        this.toggleModal()
    }

    // Want to call this function inside dispatch
    toggleModal() {
        this.setState({ modal: !this.state.modal })
    }

    render () {}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        reduxFunction: () => {
            dispatch('SOME_ASYNC_FUNCTION').then(() => {

                // How to call this function?
                toggleModal()   

                // ownProps is read-only, so can't be solved by passing modal as prop

            })
        }
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(AddInstrument)
```

Comment: You're going to call `reduxFunction` somewhere in your component. Any reason you can't just call `toggleModal` right after that?

Comment: I updated the code, but this.props.reduxFunction is not a promise, so it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

This is very high level, but you can pass in a prop `modalOpen` from the connected store.

Then, within your component, use `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.modalOpen === true && this.props.modalOpen === false) {
        this.closeModal()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that solves the issue of accessing this.closeModal() inside dispatch. componentDidUpdate won't fire when we dispatch the function

Comment: It will if your reducer contains a modalOpen attribute which is fed in as a prop during the connect

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was that the dispatch is not returning a promise.

[Promise not returning when using mapDispatchToProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524501/promise-not-returning-when-using-mapdispatchtoprops)

I made the dispatch function into a promise, and was able to use OPTION 1.

Comment: When an async handler is calling `setState` you should be sure the component is not unmounted, otherwise it'll throw an error.